# To run Node js program synchronously after for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronization

i want to execute the last `console statement` after all the `for loop` execution, but that console statement `executes immediately` when control enters `else` statement, please help me to solve this issue

```
if (false) {
  //
} else {
  //pushing the scenarios object id from project table to scenarios array
  // function async(project) {    
  // Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (i = 0; i < projectToBeDeleted[0].scenarios.length; i++) {
    scenarios.push(projectToBeDeleted[0].scenarios[i])
  }
  //iterating the scenario table to get the child scenarios from all matching scenarios
  for (i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i++) {
    query = { "_id": scenarios[i] }
    Scenario.getScenarios(query)
      .then((scenariosResponse) => {
        for (j = 0; j < scenariosResponse[0].childScenario.length; j++) {
          scenarios.push(scenariosResponse[0].childScenario[j])
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).send({
          message: error.stack
        })
      })
  }
  // })
  console.log("sync", scenarios)
}
```

Comment: you could use `async.eachSeries()` of `async` library.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal is there any other way to make this work, without using any libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `Promise.all([]).then()`.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

EDIT: example with your specific problem

```
for (i = 0; i < projectToBeDeleted[0].scenarios.length; i++) {
  scenarios.push(projectToBeDeleted[0].scenarios[i]);
}

const promises = [];
for (i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i++) {
  const query = { "_id": scenarios[i] }
  const promise = Scenario.getScenarios(query)
    .then((scenariosResponse) => {
      for (j = 0; j < scenariosResponse[0].childScenario.length; j++) {
        scenarios.push(scenariosResponse[0].childScenario[j])
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400)
        .send({
          message: error.stack
        })
    })
  promises.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log("sync", scenarios)
})
```

Comment: thank you so much.. can you please tell me what this line does `promises.push(promise)`

Comment: What you do is to `push` your promises in an array. `Promise.all` will create a new promise that will be resolved when all promises (in array `promises`) are resolved.